# Kubernetes on AWS using Kops - kube-apiserver authentication for kubectl

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I have setup a basic 2 node k8s cluster on AWS using KOPS .. I had issues connecting and interacting with the cluster using `kubectl` ... and I keep getting the error: 
        `The connection to the server api.euwest2.dev.avi.k8s.com was refused - did you specify the right host or port?` when trying to run any kubectl command .....

have done basic `kops export kubecfg --name xyz.hhh.kjh.k8s.com --config=~$KUBECONFIG` --> to export the kubeconfig for the cluster I have created. Not sure what else I'm missing to make a successful connection to the kubeapi-server to make kubectl work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like either:

- Your kube-apiserver is not running.

  - Check with `docker ps -a | grep apiserver` on your Kubernetes master.
- `api.euwest2.dev.avi.k8s.com` is resolving to an IP address where your nothing is listening.

  - `208.73.210.217`?
- You have the wrong port configured for your kube-apiserver on your ~/.kube/config

  - `server: https://api.euwest2.dev.avi.k8s.com:6443`?